# Device Availability dialog in the Developer Console shows 0 device

Tags: java, android, google-play

I just uploaded my App's APK to Play Store and in the Using the Device Availability dialog in the Developer Console it say's This application is available to over 0 devices.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What should extra need to be added to my Manifest file.

My res folder has all image for all different devices

[image]

It will be really helpful if anyone can help me on this.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xyz.ssasasas"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".A1"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="info"></activity>
        <activity android:name="Displayone"></activity>
        <activity android:name="A2" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="A2" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @RaghavSood My Manifest file: http://f.cl.ly/items/0n2n403X3v1q1r2n1T32/mani.txt

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer for this was I didn't activated the APK that I uploaded. After activating it is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your app. The Play store's developer console's been notorious for doing things like this since back when it was called the Android Market. I used to get this in a couple of my apps as well, but they both have been installed by thousands of people, so I don't think it's true.

Comment: If I publish my App and doesn't works on other device, it will be quite embarrassing for me. Are you sure this is a bug only

Comment: Yes. I'm as sure as I can be.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the manifest in the update of your app. Did you update your version code and name? this would have been an error long before you got to what devices it will work on.
Also make sure you deactivate the old app and reactivate the new that will give the 0 devices.

Comment: I am not updating any App, this is just first version I am uploading.

Comment: Did you make sure the app was active and published?